# When composing classes in python, which is preferred mixins or object attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When composing functions from mutliple classes, I have seen both of the following conventions employed: `Data1` uses mixins to add methods directly to the child class while `Data2` instantiates attribute objects that do the work.

I think they are equivalent and that the choice is just one of style.  Is that right?  Or is one preferred over the other?

```
class Data1(Reader, Processor, Writer):
   def __init__(self):
       Reader.__init__(self)
       Processor.__init__(self)
       Writer.__init__(self)

   def run(self):
       self.read()
       self.process()
       self.write()
```

or

```
class Data2:
   def __init__(self):
       self.reader = Reader()
       self.processor = Processor()
       self.writer = Writer()

   def run(self):
       self.reader.read()
       self.processor.process()
       self.writer.write()
```

To flush out a specific example, I have a processing pipeline where there are various data products that each need to be read (`Reader.read()`), processed (`Processor.process()`), and then the product of the processing step needs to be written to a db (`Writer.write()`).

To be even more concrete, consider that I have multiple fitness data types:

1. heart rate data from a csv file that needs to averaged on
   1-second intervals and dumped to a `heart-rate` table in a db
2. running speed data from a json file that needs to be converted to
   mi/hr, then formatted as part of a html report.
3. weather data from
   a web api that needs to be aggregated over day-long periods and then
   posted to another web api.

For each of these "data products", there is a logical `read`, `process`, `write` pipeline and I'd like to capture that in an abstract class that can then be used as a consistent template for handling future "data products".

In these examples, `Reader.read()` would be an abstract class that might read a csv, json, or web API.  `Processor.process()` performs various aggregations.  `Writer.write()` would send the processed data to various places.

Given that, I am unsure of the best structure.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO, but either one is fine (although you should use a `super` call instead of the `Reader.__init__(self)` etc.

Comment: what is the advantage of super in this case?  three super calls for each mixin doesn't look as tidy as this syntax and i think they are equivalent in this case.

Comment: @thebjorn would using [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) be a good fit if going with either of these implementations then? To *more-or-less* supplement the eyesore?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what is wrong with the question for SO.  "All subjective questions are expected to be constructive" from https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. It might be that the answer is: "it doesn't matter", but that doesn't make it a bad fit for SO.

Comment: If you want your Python to look like Java then I'm sure attrs will be a perfect fit for you. Personally I think it's horrendous.  The day I can give proper types to `Date(year, month, day)` I might change my mind ;-)   (...no, a month is not an integer, nor an unsigned integer...)

Comment: I have to disagree with the peoples that voted for closing this question as "primarily opinion-based" - inheritance and composition have well-defined and rather different semantics (even if technically inheritance is a restricted form of composition/delegation), so there _are_ objective reasons to choose one or the other depending on the context.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: My vote was actually that it was too broad (there simply isn't enough information in the question to distinguish which case they're asking about), but the final reason is based on the most popular close reason.

Comment: @BobBaxley is a "data product" a reader ? Is it a writer ? Is it a processor ? If you go that way, a writer uses a db connection, but does this make a writer a db connection ?

Comment: I updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I voted to close since inheritance vs. composition is one of the OOP holy wars (since the early 90s and the Self language). The original question was "[is] the choice just one of style" - which is certainly could be, at least for Python. Technically, composition has been shown to be more expressive than inheritance, but inheritance with meta classes is equivalent. Serge's well formulated answer boils down to a set of heuristics, which is a fancy way of saying opinion based ;-)  I agree with the OP that this is a constructive opinion based question, so I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to avoid a religious was because you could find technical reasons to use one or the other, but a rule of thumb is to ask the question *is A a B or does A have a B?* In former case you should use inheritance, in the latter composition.

For example, a coloured square **is** a figure and **has** a colour. So it should inherit from figure and contain a colour. There can be some hints: is one of the subobject has an independant lifecycle (it may exist before being used in the combining object) then it is with no doubt a **has a** relation. On the other side, if it cannot exist alone (*abstract* class) then is is with no doubt a **is a* relation.

But that means that without knowing what you call a `Reader` a `Writer` and a `Processor` and what data is, I cannot say which model I would use. But if `Reader` and `Writer` were both subclasses of the same ancestor class with independant parent members, I would use composition. If they were specially tailored classes sharing members of a common ancestor, that would be more of a *is a* operation and I would use inheritance.

The rule is that when possible, you should respect the real object semantics. After all in deep code execution it does not really matter whether you have used inheritance or composition.

---

BTW, what is discussed above is the general inheritance vs composition question. Strictly speaking, a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) is a special case because a mixin should maintain no state but only add methods and because of that is often abstract. In Python mixins are implemented through inheritance, but other language may have other implementations. But in Python they are a typical example of something that is not necessarily a **is a** relation but does use inheritance.

Comment: Great answer. I would just add two points : 1. objects ownership/lifecycles are also part of the forces that are in play here - with composition, the "sub" objects (Reader, Processor, Writer) in the example) could be passed as arguments to `Data2` and have their own independant lifecycle, and 2. mixins are not supposed to have a state of their own (not that they technically can't - at least in Python - but the definition of a mixin class is that it only provides behaviours).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thank you for the comment! I have tried to include it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Using superclasses is shorter (if you initialize the bases correctly):

```
class Data1(Reader, Processor, Writer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.read()
        self.process()
        self.write()
```

but many people find the composition version to be easier to work with, since you don't need to go hunting through the inheritance tree to find where a method is implemented/overriden.

Wikipedia has a longer article on the topic which is well worth the read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

*Addendum:* your `.run()` method might be better implemented as

```
self.write(self.process(self.read()))
```

and then it would be easier to just make it a function:

```
def run(reader, processor, writer):
    return writer.write(processor.process(reader.read()))
```

or with e.g. logging:

```
def run(reader, processor, writer):
    for data in reader.read():
        log.debug("Read data: %r", data)
        for output_chunk in processor.process(data):
            log.debug("processed %r and got %r", data, output_chunk)
            writer.write(output_chunk)
            log.debug("wrote %r", output_chunk)
```

and call it:

```
run(Reader(), Processor(), Writer())
```

assuming the reader is yielding data, this could be much more efficient, and it is very much easier to write unit tests for.

*Finally:* You do not need `Reader` as an abstract base class for csv, json, or web API reader classes. People coming from Java/C++ tend to conflate classes and types, and subclasses with subtypes. The Python type of the `reader` parameter in

```
def run(reader, processor, writer):
```

is ∀τ ≤ {read: NONE→DATA}, ie. all subtypes t of an object type with a `.read(..)` that takes NONE (the type of `None`) and returns a value of (here unspecified) type DATA. E.g. the standard `file` object has such a type and could be passed in directly, instead of writing a wrapper-class `FileReader` with tons of boilerplate. This, incidentally, is why I consider adding under-powered type languages to Python to be a very bad thing, but at this point I realize that I'm digressing ;-)

Comment: Great link. Thanks!

Comment: Given this is a Python 3 question, the `__init__` can be even shorter (no need to pass arguments to `super`): `super().__init__()`

Comment: @thebjorn: Yar. Of course, that leaves `__init__` as a no-op, so it doesn't even need to be defined (the `__init__` for `Reader` would be called automatically, and it would be up to it to call `super` to continue the initialization in the other bases). But yeah, if the OP's case is more complicated, that would be the base.